# Timing python function

Tags: python, timeit

(Python 2.7.8, Windows)

there is so many questions already about this particular subject, but I cannot seem to get any of them working.

So, what I'm trying to accomplish is timing how long a function takes to execute.

I have functions.py and main.py in following fashion:

```
#functions.py
def function(list):
    does something
    return list
...

#main.py
import functions
...stuff...
while:
    list = gets list from file
    functions.function(list) <--- this needs to get timed
```

Now I tried `time.time()` the start and end points first, but it's not accurate enough (difference tends to be 0.0), and after some googling it seems that this isn't the way to go anyway. Apparently what I should use(?) is `timeit` module. However I cannot understand how to get the function into it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, there's a Python module made for this very task, `timeit`. Its syntax, while a little idiosyncratic, is quite easy to understand:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000)
```

`stmt` is the function call to be measured, in your case: `functions.function(list)`

`setup` is the code you need to create the context necessary for `stmt` to execute, in your case: `import functions; list = gets list from file`

`number` is how many time `timeit` would run `stmt` to find its average execution time. You might want to change the number, since calling your function a million times might take a while.

tl;dr:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='functions.function(list)', setup='import functions; list = gets list from file', number=100)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is mostly what I had tried, but apparently my syntax for setup was off.

Answer (score 0):

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
my_function()
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start
```

Comment: This seems to work, however according to documentation "On either platform, default_timer() measures wall clock time, not the CPU time. This means that other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing." And if the function goes directly to timeit, it makes multiple passes which probably increaces accuracy. Is this something I should be conserned about, or is this trivial?

Comment: you normally want wall clock time, which accounts for context switching and side effects that take time not measured by pure processor timing.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg are you sure? unless he explicitly want to take into account IO time and other side effects, the way to benchmark algorithm is to measure CPU time. At least it is in academia.

Comment: @oxymor0n it really depends on what the function does, but in most cases, I've always wanted wall time.  for computationally intensive algorithms, the situation might be different... but if you do any I/O, you definitely want wall time.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg the thing about measuring wall time though, is that it introduce so many other variables into your measurement. Not just I/O, but your system load and other processes will interfere with your timing. How do you account for those variance?

Answer (score 0):

you see this demo: `time.time`

```
>>> def check(n):
...     start = time.time()
...     for x in range(n):
...         pass     
...     stop = time.time()
...     return stop-start
... 
>>> check(1000)
0.0001239776611328125
>>> check(10000)
0.0012159347534179688
>>> check(100)
1.71661376953125e-05
```

the above function returns hum much time in sec taken by for for n loops.

so the algorithm is:

```
start = time.time()
# your stuff
stop = time.time()
time_taken = stop - start
```

Comment: Are you using Linux? Apparently different OS's use time.time and time.clock differently. If i replace your code's .time with .clock I get same-looking results.

Comment: @questions989 then enjoy it :)

Comment: depending on platform, your highest resolution timer might only be as granular as about 16ms.  so small (< 16ms) values may get reported as 0.0